# Customized odd and even headings with Koma-Script and a predefined first page

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

I want to create a document with KOMA Script and customized headings for odd/even pages *and* a predefined first page.

I tried the MWE below, but it seems that the rest of the even pages are affected by the definition of `firstpage`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

% create new header for title page
\renewcommand*\titlepagestyle{firstpage}
\newpairofpagestyles{firstpage}{%
  \ihead{1st page left head}
  \ohead{1st page right head}
}

   \clearscrheadings

\cohead{center odd pages \headmark}
\cehead{center even pages (after 1st page) \headmark} % <=== THIS IS NOT WORKING

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Document Title}
\author{Document Author}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-16]

\end{document}
```

Any help will be appreciated very much!

Comment: Why don't you simply make the titlepage from scratch and avoid messing with page sryles?

Comment: Thanks Johannes_B, but I want to use the template for several documents.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280 and the wikibooks page linked there.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is about headings in odd/even pages like in journal articles, i.e. with a predefined first page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the odd/even style to work out of the box, you need to specify the document option `[twoside]`:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

% create new header for title page
\renewcommand*\titlepagestyle{firstpage}
\newpairofpagestyles{firstpage}{%
  \ihead{1st page left head}
  \ohead{1st page right head}
}

   \clearscrheadings

\cohead{center odd pages \headmark}
\cehead{center even pages (after 1st page) \headmark} % <=== THIS IS NOT WORKING

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Document Title}
\author{Document Author}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-16]

\end{document}
```

Alternatively if you don't want to specify `twoside` you can use the `\ifthispageodd` macro provided by KOMA and use

```
\chead{\ifthispageodd{center odd pages \headmark}{center even pages (after
  1st page) \headmark}}
```

instead of `\cehead` and `\cohead`. Note that this needs two LaTeX-runs to be correct.

Comment: That was it. The `twoside`option is the answer. Thanks